# How to shuffle values in a matrix or data frame so that each value only occurs once in each row/column?

Tags: r, matrix, shuffle, sample, shift

How to shuffle values in a matrix or data frame so that each value only occurs once in each row/column in R?

For example, here is what I have:

```
A, A, A, A
B, B, B, B
C, C, C, C
D, D, D, D
E, E, E, E
F, F, F, F
G, G, G, G
```

What I Want:

```
A, B, C, D
B, C, D, E
C, D, E, F
D, E, F, G
E, F, G, A
F, G, A, B
G, A, B, C
```

I either need to shift the column up/down and wrap it to maintain my inputs or do it through some sort of shuffle function that shuffles the columns in a way that still ensures the rows do not repeat.

Comment: Hi, it seems that your question is not really a question about R. Before asking how to shuffle in 'R', you should specify what precisely you mean with shuffling.  For example, how would you do it in another programming language?  Basically, you are trying to construct a [Latin square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square), so you should look for algorithms that construct Latin squares.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `outer` + `%%` to produce circular shift

```
v <- LETTERS[1:4]
out <- matrix(
  v[outer(seq_along(v) - 1, seq_along(v) - 1, `+`) %% length(v) + 1],
  nrow = length(v)
)
```

such that

```
> out
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"
[2,] "B"  "C"  "D"  "A"
[3,] "C"  "D"  "A"  "B"
[4,] "D"  "A"  "B"  "C"
```

---

**Update**
If your matrix is not square, you can try the code like below

```
v <- LETTERS[1:7]
out <- t(
  head(
    matrix(
      v[outer(seq_along(v) - 1, seq_along(v) - 1, `+`) %% length(v) + 1],
      nrow = length(v)
    ), 4
  )
)
```

which gives

```
> out
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"
[2,] "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"
[3,] "C"  "D"  "E"  "F" 
[4,] "D"  "E"  "F"  "G"
[5,] "E"  "F"  "G"  "A"
[6,] "F"  "G"  "A"  "B"
[7,] "G"  "A"  "B"  "C"
```

Comment: the example i used was not the most accurate as my actual data is not a square, it is a 4x30 matrix with numbers 1:30 down each of the 5 columns. Your code works great but it cut my data down to a 4x4 matrix rather than shuffling or shifting all the data